# PhpStorm using Command Line Console Tool from inside Vagrant with Command Line Tools Support Aliases

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, virtualbox, homestead, command-line-tool

I like [Command Line Console Tool](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/command-line-tools-in-phpstorm/) in PhpStorm more than Terminal. It's much easier to use, and there is [Command Line Tool Support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6630-command-line-tool-support) extension, that could bring aliases for Symfony or Composer. However, this could be possible just for local directories, but I want to log into my Vagrant Homestead machine and use this from inside.

Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best I can suggest is to create local batch/shell script that gets parameters and then executes final command on your remote host (be it Vagrant/SSH or even Docker).

Other than that -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23740 -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.